# Is it possible to know if the car part is going to fit be just looking at the car VIN and comparing them

Tags: car, part-identification, vehicle-identification

suppose I have a car lamp with an ID on it,and my car has a VIN(Vehicle identification number) on it,can I compare something in the ID to know if the part comes from the same manufacturer or that part is for  that same car at least.

[VIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_identification_number)

Comment: Are you seeking a simple way to just compare the numbers? No chance.  You need to take make/model/year and look up in the manufacturers parts manual.

Comment: @agentp The VIN that is in every car gives you the make/model and year,now suppose I have the number and then I went and bought a car light does this light have an identification code that would tell me if it is meant for that car by just comparing the VIN with the code on the light

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you mean by "comparing". If by comparing you mean taking both numbers to your local dealer and asking them to look in the parts manual to see if you have the right part, then yes.  Otherwise say more clearly what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Not with 100% certainty.

Why do I say this?

Well, had a brand new vehicle that I was fitting the radio into and the vin and vehicle spec sheet showed a 4 speed gearbox, even the gear knob had the 4 speed pattern.

On road test and had not noticed but changed up to 5th.... The factory had fitted a 5 speed box... Checked with production at the factory and they said « we must have run out of 4 speed boxes at that instant so fitted a 5 ». This can be a consequence of JIT as the line must continue...

It was really rare though.

Another one can be braking systems some vehicles can have a Bendix while others of same model Delphi...

So, to be sure and certain, you have to check what is actually fitted.